# Tool to graphically customize the Nimbus look and feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am looking for a tool that I used a few months ago, but I am not able to remember the name.

This is a graphical tool for customizing the Nimbus Swing look and feel. On the right side of the window, there was a set of sample Swing components, and on the left the list of all customizable properties (the same than the result of `UIManager.getDefaults()`). The tool allows to change the values of the properties (color, font, integer values), and to see the result on the right side in real time.

The tool allows to export the changes in a file, too (the java code that sets the customized values).

I remember that the whole program was only one big java file. And I think this tool was part of another project (the tool is standalone, though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found it. The name of the tool is *[NimbusThemeCreator](http://code.google.com/p/aephyr/source/browse/trunk/src/test/aephyr/swing/NimbusThemeCreator.java?r=46)*, and it is part of the project *[Aephyr](http://code.google.com/p/aephyr/)*.

Comment: That looks awesome! Can you describe how to javac it and get it running? Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is just one Java class (and inner classes)  with a main function and no external dependencies. So, just download the file, compile it with `javac NimbusThemeCreator.java` and then run with `java MimbusThemeCreator`.

Comment: By the way, this should work with Java 7. For Java 6 I think you will have to comment out the `Painter` class import (the `Painter` class was an internal class (namespace `com.sun.java.swing`) in Java 6 and was promoted to the public namespace `javax.swing` in Java 7).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's what I tried, but it failed. I get an error saying `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: NimbusThemeCreator (wrong name: test/NimbusThemeCreator)` where `test/` is the folder I have the `NimbusThemeCreator.java` file (`~/test/`). I tried with the same commands you suggested.

Comment: Sorry, you also have to remove the `package` declaration at the top of the file, too. Also, don't try to run the code using `java test/NimbusThemeCreator`, but with `java -cp test NimbusThemeCreator`