# Changing JScrollPane on JComboboxBox

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jcombobox, look-and-feel

I'm new here so please forgive me if I do something wrong...

I am using S`eaglass Look-and-Feel` and it uses `JScrollPane` in case of large number of items. I would like to change it so that it uses `Nimbus look-and-feel JScrollPane` instead.

I tried changing ui on `JComboBox`, however it only changes the "outer" appearance, not the scroll pane itself.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: I tried this, but it changes only the outer appearance (metal ui in this try)...

```
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    combo.setUI(new MetalComboBoxUI());
```

EDIT2: Alternatively how can I change all JScrollPanes in project to use nimbus UI and for other components to use some other UI?

Comment: better would be send here code to show us what you are tried, isn't clear for me

Comment: hmmm, as I described http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520803/combining-customized-java-lookandfeel-classes, that's not good idea mixing Look & Feel, but there are exists Custom L&F that allowed mixing Built-in Themes, or you have to create own JComponents, but that isn't easy job :-), but not hard

Answer (score 2):

for applied any changes for [JComponets UI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) you have to call

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myFrame);
```

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242341/jcombobox-change-drop-down-popup) is probably better for your issue

Comment: Hah! I managed to overcome it with a little trick. I extracted source code of look and feel, changed what I needed in scrollpaneUI class, included it in project and it shows scroll pane UI differently now :)